# Why is -(2+i) also a root of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

$z^6-7z^4+31z^2-25=0$ has a root $2+i$. I figured that $2-i$ is also a root as complex roots come in conjugate pairs...But:

1) How do I prove that $-(2+i)$ is also a root

2) How do I find other roots? Assuming there are three more.

Comment: Subsrtitute $2+i$ for $z$ and perform calculations.

Comment: Because all powers of $z$ that occur in the polynomial are even, that means that if $r$ is a root, then so is $-r$. In particular, if $(2+i)$ is a root, then so is $-(2+i)$ (and, as you  note, since the equation has real coefficients, so are $2-i$ and $-(2-i)$).

Answer (score 1):

By the factor theorem, if $2+i$ is a root, then $z^6−7z^4+31z^2−25=0$ when $z=2+i$. So this is how you prove the first part.

For your first question, if you notice that the polynomial only involves even powers of $z$, this means that the negated version of the roots are also roots because when you square them, the $-1$ becomes $1$, they also fit the factor theorem condition.

Since you know four roots out of six ($2+i,\ 2-i,\ -2+i,\ -2-i$), you can try out other values, or use the sum or product of roots formulae to find them.  So you know that the sum of roots is $0$ because the coefficient of $z^5$ is zero, this means that your two remaining roots sum to zero as well, because the four roots you found previously cancel each other out.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the equation set $x=z^2$ to get $x^3-7x^2+31x-25=0$. The root $x=1$ is evident. Then $x^3-7x^2+31x-25=(x-1)(x^2-6x+25)=0$. Now solve the quadratic equation $x^2-6x+25=0$. You have $x_1=1$, $x_2=3+4i$ and $x_3=3-4i$.
Then solve $z^2=x$ for each $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1) was answered in a comment:
since the polynomial has only even terms, you can treat it as a
polynomial of $z^2$:
$$ (z^2)^3-7(z^2)^2+31(z^2)-25=0.$$
You can make the cubic polynomial more obvious by setting $w=z^2,$ so that
$$ w^3-7w^2+31w-25=0.$$

Then each solution gives you a value of $w=z^2,$ but if
and if $z$ is a root of the original polynomial then
$z^2 = w$ is a root of the cubic,
and since $(-z)^2 = w$ as well, $-z$ is also a root of the original polynomial.
Since you know $2+i$ is a root, you know that $-(2+i)$ is one too.

For part 2),
you already know that the conjugate of each root is a root
(since the polynomial has real coefficients).
That gives you two more roots, $2-i$ and $-(2-i)$.
So the original polynomial is something of the form
$$(z - (2+i))(z - (2-i))(z+(2+i))(z+(2-i)) Q(z),$$
where $Q(z)$ is a polynomial.
You can multiply the known factors together and find that
$$ (z - (2+i))(z - (2-i))(z+(2+i))(z+(2-i)) = z^4 - 6 z^2 + 25.$$
Therefore the original polynomial is actually
$$
z^6-7z^4+31z^2-25 = (z^4 - 6 z^2 + 25) Q(z).
$$
You can use synthetic division to find $Q(z).$
It's a very easy division;
in fact it should be almost immediately obvious that 
$Q(z) = z^2 - 1$ is the only possible result, since the leading term
has to be $z^6/z^4 = z^2$, the final term has to be $-25/25 = -1,$
and there can't be any non-zero term with an odd power of $z.$

The roots of $z^2 - 1$ are very easy to find, and they are the final two roots.